# How to enable a component's property when i transitionToRoute

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Hello i have a search component on page header.
 When i click on a magnifyng glass, a `flag` property is getting `true`, so the `search-box` component is displayed like so:

[image]

When i press Enter on the magnifying glass i call an action, which, inside the `application/controller.js` it makes a redirection to a `result-page`, like so:

```
`actions: {
updateQuery(query) {
  return this.transitionToRoute('search-results', {
    queryParams: {
      query
    }
  })
 }
}
```

The redirections works as  expected and the results-page loads, but the `search-box` component is still displayed! I havent found a way to disable the property flag , that it is inside the `header` component, yet.

Any ideas how to trigger that, when i do the redirection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage `flag` property in your `application/controller.js` and pass it to your header as 2-way-binding like `flag=flag` and bind it to your search component. Then, in your `updateQuery` action of your controller you can set the `flag` to false like this:

```
updateQuery(){
  this.set('flag', false);
  this.transitionToRoute('search-results');
}
```

You can take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/47f49a8f49c53e80abe48f04ebf933a7) for this usage.